# Generate @WebService with Eclipse Annotation Processing

Tags: web-services, rad, eclipse-jdt, generated-code, annotation-processing

I'm using the Eclipse Annotation Processing feature to generate a webservice client. My Processor extends "javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor" and is itself annotated (@SupportedAnnotationTypes) to only process my custom annotation. Using the filer from the ProcessingEnvironment I generate a new ClassB which i annotate with @WebService.

My processor returns true because the annotation i'm processing is my custom annotation.

It seems that this @WebService method is not picked up by the tooling (another annotation processer i assume (?)) and therefore doesn't show in the virtual 'Services' folder.

I've tried changing the order of the processors but that has no effect.

Other, not generated classes, immediately show up in the virtual "Services" folder when annotated with @WebService and with that i am able to run the test client. My generated ClassB is not detected as a webservice.

Any idea how i can have my generated class be detected as webservice show up in the virtual 'Services' folder ?

This all is happening in a Java EE Web project.
Using: Rational Application Developer Version: 8.0.4 iFix1 (Build ID: RADO804iFix1-I20120127_2338) which is Eclipse version 3.6.2.

Thanks.